# Combine CURL and Simple HTML DOM for scraping data

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

I have assigned a task to scrape data from a site which is password protected, I did it through CURL but now i want to get link inside that html returned by CURL, and go to that link and grab data from there. I passed the response of `CURL` into `file_get_contents()` but not working. Here is my `CURL` code.

```
$ckfile = tempnam("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML,    like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.3 Safari/533.2';

$username = "XXXXXX";
$password = "XXXXXX";


$f = fopen('log.txt', 'w'); // file to write request header for debug purpose


$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

 $html = curl_exec($ch);

 curl_close($ch);

preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*?)" />~', $html, $viewstate);
preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION"   value="(.*?)" />~', $html, $eventValidation);

$viewstate = $viewstate[1];
$eventValidation = $eventValidation[1];




$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $f);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

// Collecting all POST fields
$postfields = array();
$postfields['__EVENTTARGET'] = "";
$postfields['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = "";
$postfields['__VIEWSTATE'] = $viewstate;
$postfields['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = $eventValidation;
$postfields['ctl00$LoginPopup1$Login1$UserName'] = $username;
$postfields['ctl00$LoginPopup1$Login1$Password'] = $password;
$postfields['ctl00$LoginPopup1$Login1$LoginButton'] = 'Log In';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$ret = curl_exec($ch); // Get result after login page.
```

Here is simple html dom code

```
$html = file_get_contents($ret);
```

This is error i am getting

```
Warning: file_get_contents(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Any other suggestion how to do it will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: $ret would be the response from curl_exec and won't be a file name or location, if you output $ret what do you get? Are you wanting the HTML of the response from the curl request?

Comment: $ret give me 1 in response.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting the HTML output of the page you are sending the request to, try setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true`, then `$ret` should contain the HTML of the page after you have CURL'd one out.

I wouldn't use `DOMDocument` to parse the response, as the HTML from the page may not be correctly formatted and `DOMDocument` will complain.

If you are just looking for links you could use `preg_match_all` on the HTML.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Actually i already know the next link where i have to go and grab data from. But the problem, i am not sure how to do it. Either `simple html dom` works with curl or not. For example my cookie and sessions are stored using curl now i have url='google.com' where i need to go and grab data, how i can do it in the same file?

Answer (score 0):

Like MajorCaiger says, you need to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to true, and then load that with `str_get_html`:

```
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$doc = str_get_html($html);
```

Even still, I don't think you have much of a chance of success with this, those asp forms are very tricky.